# NotSupportedException- это плохая практика?

Tags: c#, .net

Собственно вопрос в том, а на сколько правильно использовать `NotSupportedException`?

Обычно, это используется в интерфейсах, когда отдельная фича может быть не реализована.

Не проще ли сделать отдельный интерфейс без необходимого метода?

Comment: Интерфейсы ничего не могут знать о конечной реализации

Comment: Если метод не [может быть] реализован, обычно применяют более каноничный в данном плане `NotImplementedException`

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если метод не реализован применяют всё же `NotImplementedException`, `NotSupportedException` используется, если какой-либо функционал, предусмотренный контрактом или базовым типом не может быть реализован. Например, в BCL есть базовый абстрактный тип `Stream`, у которого есть метод `Seek`, устанавливающий позицию в потоке. Этот метод прекрасно работает с `MemoryStream` и `FileStream`, но, например, в NetworkStream -- нет, что абсолютно логично. Соответственно, в случае вызова метода `Seek` у объекта этого типа выбросится как раз `NotSupportedExcption`, то есть мы как бы говорим: "Бро, мы бы с радостью реализовали, но в данном случае это невозможно/не нужно", тогда как `NotImplementedException` чаще всего говорит о том, что функционал не реализован на данный момент, например, когда только-только появился Mono, в нем это исключение бросала добрая половина методов.

Касательно правильности использования могу высказать лишь мнение. Я считаю, что правильность зависит от контекста использования, то есть, да, стоит следовать принципу "I" из SOLID и разделять интерфейсы: раз чего-то нельзя делать, то не надо давать и такой возможности, принципу "L", кстати, тоже не очень хорошо от такого поведения типов-наследников. Однако, есть случаи, когда сделать это невозможно или затруднительно, есть много уже написанного кода в библиотеках и фреймворках, есть огромное количество оберток над низкоуровневыми системными вызовами, тот же класс `Stream`, в котором, кстати говоря, есть свойство `CanSeek` и это -- хорошо и правильно.

Резюмируя, имхо, есть случаи, когда без его использования не обойтись, но использовать его в новом коде, а тем более в коде бизнес-логики, думаю не стоит.